# How to delete nested record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller, parameter-passing

My girl model has comments with using gem 'acts_as_commentable'

When I access example.com/girls/show/1
It shows ID#1 girl's profile.
All the posted comments are shown in the bottom of this page.

For each comment row, I want to add delete button to delete a comment.

If it should pass the parameter to girls_controller.rb's comment_destroy action.
How action part and view should be??

It keeps **undefined local variable or method `girls'**  error with codes below.

"girls/show.html.erb" view should be something like this. Just a part.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>

<% @all_comments.each do |comment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment.id %></td>
    <td><%= comment.title %></td>
    <td><%= comment.body %></td>
    <td><%= comment.subject %></td>
    <td><%= button_to 'comment_destroy', girls, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :disable_with => 'deleting...', method: :delete %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

girls_controller.rb's comment_destroy action should be something like this

```
  def comment_destroy
    @comment = comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to girls_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
    redirect_to :controller => 'girls', :action => 'show', :id => params[:girls][:id]
    flash[:notice] = "comment deleted!"
  end
```

Comment: You should add your routes to your question. But it seems you need to read and study how to deal with CRUD. Have a look at the official guide, the railscasts or the Rails for zombies courses at codeschool.com

Comment: Use AJAX or look into the `_destroy` "param".

Comment: Thanks!! What should I add to view part to pass the parameters???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have comments nested under a girl, and you want to delete the comment.

Routes

```
resources :girls do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Then, you have a comments controller that handles your creation and destroy.

```
<%= button_to 'comment_destroy', [@girl, comment], confirm: 'Are you sure?', :disable_with => 'deleting...', method: :delete %>
```

The destroy method in your comments controller:

```
def destroy
  @girl = Girl.find(params[:girl_id])
  @comment = @girl.comments.find(params[:id])
  if @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @girl, notice: "Comment Removed"
  else
    redirect_to @girl, error: "We could not remove the comment"
  end
end
```

end

UPDATE -- based on user's request to use a non-restful solution

Routes:

```
resources :girls do
  member do
    delete :delete_comment, to: "girls#delete_comment", as: "delete_comment"
  end
end
```

controller

```
def delete_comment
  @girl = Girl.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @girl.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
  if @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @girl, notice: "Comment Removed"
  else
    redirect_to @girl, error: "We could not remove the comment"
  end
end
```

View link

```
<%= button_to 'comment_destroy', delete_comment_path(@girl, comment_id: comment.id), confirm: 'Are you sure?', :disable_with => 'deleting...', method: :delete %>
```

Final note: I really don't like this solution. You should have a Comments controller and go with my first solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advise:) but what if you want to delete girl's record?? it seems that you are replacing destroy action of girls model.

Comment: do you mean putting this method on comments_controller.rb??? I don't have one. am I supposed to make one instead of writing it in girls_controller.rb??? or can you still write it in girls_controller?

Comment: @MKK So are you trying to delete a girl record? It's not very usual to see a delete of parent record on the child record.

Comment: I just want 2 options to delete either parent record or child record in the same controller(girls controller at this time):)

Comment: I am trying to delete child record(comment) on parent's controller(girl).

Comment: @MKK  Updated with a solution that keeps the comment deletion in your girls controller. Not recommended.

Comment: thanks!! I replaced it with the code you put. However it still gets undefined method `delete_comment_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000008082ac0>:0x000000080767c0>

Comment: Let's give up on this solution. Thanks for the help, though. You can put nested field(children's) on the parent's view. But you have to go to children's controller when you would like to delete. Is is regular way in rails, right?

Comment: The regular way would be to post to the children's controller, but the user does not have to go there.

Comment: How does that happen? if you just chose children's controller and action, it only does deleting action but the user won't move to children's view??? Is this what you mean? sorry. I'm so newbie.

Comment: @MKK .. yes, in my destroy action, it redirects no matter what.